# download a mp3 file to iphone problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsurlconnection

I developing an iPhone application..and i facing one problem that i need to download an mp3 file from some **FTP** server and i used `NSURLConnection` with `NSURLRequest` 
But every time i facing this error

> error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x187650 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ftp://....../you.mp3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=ftp://....you.mp3, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x17cb20 "The request timed out."}

What is this mean and how can i download this file OR correct this error??

**NOTE: I did this exapme using HTTP server and it worj JUST for FTP give this error**
any advice please :)

Comment: Have you tried ASIHTTPRequest? http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/